# Test state update function passed in props of a component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to learn testing in react with Jest and Enzyme and I'd like to test a switch component I made:

```js
import Switch from "./index";
import { mount,  ReactWrapper} from "enzyme";

describe("[UNIT] Testing Switch component", () => {


  let wrapper: ReactWrapper
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Switch/>)
  })


  describe('Component validation', () => {

    let initialState = wrapper.state("state")

    wrapper.simulate("click")
    it('should toggle value', function () {
      expect(wrapper.state("state")).toEqual(!initialState)
    });
  })
})
```

The thing is that my Switch component takes two props, state and setState, normally defined by a useState hook in the parent component.

How could I implement a fake "useState"? Or am I totally wrong in my testing philosophy?

Comment: Right now you're passing _no_ props to `Switch` when you mount it. If it takes a `state` value and a `setState` callback, then _pass those in_ - it's none of the component's business whether they're generated by `useState` or not.

Comment: So I can just create a classic variable and a function that updates it ? And it will work ?

Comment: The function doesn't actually have to update the variable - again, that's not the business of the component you're testing. It gets a value and a function, it doesn't even know if they're connected. In general I'd recommend **not** directly passing the setter function `useState` returns, as then the parent loses control of its own state.

Comment: Ohhh okay I get it ! Thanks ! How would you create a "Switch" component in that case ? Because I need the switch to update a parent's state (I thought that passing states as props was the best solution but I can be wrong)

Comment: You've provided no context as to what this `Switch` component does, so it's hard to be specific, but I'd suggest the actual setter call stay in the parent, close to the value it's changing, so if you have `const [thing, setThing] = useState(thing)` you'd use `<Child value={thing} onChange={(value) => setThing(value)} />`, rather than just `<Child value={thing} onChange={setThing} />`.